# Regarding Symfony Test Cases

Tags: symfony, testcase

In Symfony2 every bundle gives a folder named Tests. Can any body explain how to run those cases. I tried, with following links but no success.

[Testing](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html) and 
[Running Symfony2 Tests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/tests.html)

Comment: Well, that second link is a link to the contributing documentation. That is meant if you are contributing the Symfony2 source code, you shouldn't look in the contributing documentation if you haven't planned to contribute the code.

Comment: @ Wouter J. Friend I really don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phpunit -c app/` run at the root of your Symfony install will run all tests for Bundles in the src/ directory.

If you'd like to run the tests of a particular Bundle then from your application root you can use

```
phpunit -c app/ path/to/Tests
```

Comment: A note: the `-c app/` switch is a shorthand for `--configuration app/` which says to PHPunit: "Look inside the app/ directory for a `phpunit.xml.dist` file (that's the config file for PHPunit)." That file is automaticly set up by Symfony2 and it isn't needed to change anything, it tells PHPunit where to look for the tests (inside the `src/*/Tests` directories)